# How do you set the max width and gridcolumns in BootStrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to set the width to 960px. Currently it is 979px. I see in variables.less you get:

```
@navbarCollapseWidth:             960px;
```

And more importantly, things like:

```
@gridColumns:             16;
@gridColumnWidth:         60px;
@gridGutterWidth:         10px;
```

However, changing these don't affect any of the standard Bootstrap features?

Comment: Do you compile the less files into CSS after making changes ? [Less compilation](http://lesscss.org/#usage). Or download directly your customized CSS with the [boostrap customize page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables)

Comment: I do compile the "less" files, but I don't know which file to edit that contains gridRowWidth in order to make these changes reflect across the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[How do I get a 16 column responsive layout with Twitter Bootstrap 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233260/how-do-i-get-a-16-column-responsive-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap-2)

it is refering to `line 517 of the mixins` you have to look for `_mixins.less` (i guess .less because i use the .scss version)

Another small thing (just a typo?): When using 16 cols, `@gridColumnWidth: 60px` sums up to 960px itself :)

Comment: How  can I tell which file actually contains the newly generated code?

Comment: "Normally", after compiling you only have 1 file in the end. I have a gathering file, that includes all the files needed ( first import your own vars, next import bootstrap, then your own assets, and bootstrap-responsive (when needed) at last. I end up with 1 css-file with everything included and compiled.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816089/why-bootstrap-css-is-not-overriding-in-other-project-with-the-same-code/12819825#12819825

Comment: if you still have comments on in your compiled file, you could search for the origin as there should be a comment for every line e.g. `/* line 613, C:/Users/name/folders/sass/bootstrap/_mixins.scss */`

Answer (score 0):

you might be wanting to edit the media queries within the bootstrap file so its not set on a 979px max-width or min-width
also, this math might help you get the calculations right for the sizes of the columns and gutters

```
@gridRowWidth: (@gridColumns * @gridColumnWidth) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@gridColumns - 1));
```

Comment: So which file is that exactly?

Comment: the bootstrap.css file you can find the media queries at the bottom,
you can change `@media (min-width: 796px) and (max-width: 976px) {` and changing the max-width to something like 960 might help get it smaller, but there might be other places you'll have to add that to with the media queries.. I made my website on that screen size 890 by simply editing all the media queries min and max width
 and the calculation of the gridRowWidth came from [variables.less](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L272)